# Is there a way to create a less mixin that calculates a grid which divides the space available?

Tags: less, grid-layout

We prefer grids that divide the available space like this:

- grid-1 = 100%
- grid-2 = 50%
- grid-3 = 33.33333333%

We have the following less mixin which works great except that grid-1 should equal 100%;

```
@column-gutter-width: 2%;

.grid {
  margin-left: -@column-gutter-width;
  .clearfix();

  .generate-grid-units(@i) when (@i > 0){
    .grid-@{i} {
      width: (100% / @i) - @column-gutter-width;
      margin-left: @column-gutter-width;
    }
    .generate-grid-units((@i - 1));
  }
  .generate-grid-units(6);
}
```

This generates the following where the only incorrect unit is grid-1:

```
.grid .grid-2 {
  width: 48%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.grid .grid-1 {
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

How can we alter the math so that grid-1 = 100% but have the other grid units remain the same?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: `width: (100% / @i - @column-gutter-width * min((@i - 1), 1));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
@column-gutter-width: 2%;
@num-columns: 6;

.grid {
  margin-left: -@column-gutter-width;
  .clearfix();

  .generate-grid-units(@i) when (@i > 1){
    .grid-@{i} {
      width: ((100% / @i) - @column-gutter-width);
      margin-left: @column-gutter-width;

      &:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
    .generate-grid-units((@i - 1));
  }
  .generate-grid-units(@num-columns);
  .grid-1 {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

To clarify:

- the loop only runs when `@i > 1`
- `.grid-1` is set manually
- `@num-columns` is actualy used to generate the grid
- `width: ((100% / @i) - @column-gutter-width);` now outputs final value rather than an expression

Comment: Thanks Tims, that's the workaround we're currently using! But is there a way to calculate it in the formula like the bootstrap gird? We've tried dissecting their grid but can't make it work when dividing the available space. Cheers